# Why doesn't this check for nil in go work?

Tags: go

In the first code example, I get errors for the "if pr != nil" line:

```
for sup, _ := range supervisorToColor {
        pr := emailToPerson[sup]
        // The line below causes the compilation error:
        // ./myprog.go:1046: missing condition in if statement
        // ./myprog.go:1046: pr != nil evaluated but not used
        if pr != nil 
        {   
          local := peopleOnFloor[pr.Email]
          sp := &Super{pr, local}
          names = append(names, sp) 
        }   
}
```

If I comment out the nil check if statement, it compiles fine:

```
for sup, _ := range supervisorToColor {
        pr := emailToPerson[sup]
        // if pr != nil 
        // {
          local := peopleOnFloor[pr.Email]
          sp := &Super{pr, local}
          names = append(names, sp) 
        // }
}
```

At first I was inclined to think it was some syntax error earlier in the code, but the fact that it works when I comment out the lines makes me think it's something else.

emailToPerson is of type map[string]*Person where Person is a struct

Thanks in advance.  Apologies if this turns out to be something incredibly simple.

Comment: *always* format your code (`go fmt` or `goimports`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The open curly brace needs to be on the same line as the `if`:

```
if pr != nil {
```

From the [Go spec on semicolons](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Semicolons):

> The formal grammar uses semicolons ";" as terminators in a number of productions. Go programs may omit most of these semicolons using the following two rules:
>
> 1. When the input is broken into tokens, a semicolon is automatically inserted into the token stream immediately after a line's final token if that token is
>
>    - an identifier
>    - an integer, floating-point, imaginary, rune, or string literal
>    - one of the keywords `break`, `continue`, `fallthrough`, or `return`
>    - one of the operators and delimiters `++`, `--`, `)`, `]`, or `}`
> 2. To allow complex statements to occupy a single line, a semicolon may be omitted before a closing "`)`" or "`}`".

This means that your code was equivalent to:

```
if pr != nil;
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info.   I think I had actually tried that before, but some other error was occurring at that time.

I understand the convenience of Go inserting semi-colons, but I almost wish explicit semi-colons were required, if for no other reason than it makes compiler errors much easier to understand.